# Understanding the performance boost behind type casting in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.3

I am running a PostGIS server (version 2.3). I have a table with the following structure:

```
- index: BIGINT
- geometry: LINESTRING
```

I was playing with some of my spatial queries ([ST_Intersects](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) in this case) to understand the performance better. I had a query that looked like

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ST_Intersects('SRID=4326;POINT(x, y)', my_table.geometry)`

As you can tell, table structure and query itself are all simple. Note that `geometry` column has only `LINESTRING`s that follows the same coordinate system (referred with SRID 4326).

As soon as I updated my query with a type cast (`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ST_Intersects('SRID=4326;POINT(x, y)'::geometry, my_table.geometry)`), the performance improved by 10-20x.

Is this happening because PostGIS doesn't need to find out if input geometry is geometry or geography? Not sure, because the second argument of `ST_Intersects` is guaranteed to be a geometry, because it was created with the following query: `SELECT AddGeometryColumn('my_table', 'geometry', 4326, 'LINESTRING', 2);`.

Does anybody have any insight on what would be reason for the performance boost with the type cast?

Comment: It probably just gives the planner enough info to go the index route

Comment: A postgis performance question is never complete without the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` outputs.